# VB.Net and Namespaces for all project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, namespaces

I'm developing an web application using VB.Net, and I would like to know, if is there any way to make a namespace to be viewed by all project without necessary Imports ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Right click on the project and choose properties. Navigate to the References tab and tick the namespaces you want imported automatically. There are usually several that are ticked by default including `System`, `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, etc.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the awser. I open the properties of my web application and nativate until References Tabs, but there's no a component for me tick in the namespaces. I try to a double click on my namespaces but it doesn't work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I found the solution like you said! Thanks Brain!